# How can I reduce overscan in 1080p with AMD HD 6xxx - Ubuntu 12.10 over HDMI

Tags: drivers, 12.10, ati, hdmi

My TV and/or receiver do not have native scaling options, nor would that be feasible. Installation of ANY Catalyst drivers (12.9, 12.10, and 12.11 beta) do not seem to work with Ubuntu 12.10 (disappearing Unity on 12.9, 12.10, and a black screen on the 12.11 beta). This is over HDMI through a Denon AV-789 receiver and a Sharp Aquos LC52D85U TV.

Now, I know the proprietary drivers have scaling options (command is sudo aticonfig --tv-geometry XxY+offset-offset)

Do the native 12.10 drivers have some option like this? I am unable to reduce the significant overscan (it's enough to push most of the stock launcher off the screen, and no upper menu bar).

Thanks!

Ubuntu 12.10
Drivers tested: AMD 12.6 (non operational), 12.9 (no unity), 12.10 (no unity, requires additional packages e.g., i386), 12.11 (black screen)

ASUS AMD EAH6950 (ATI HD 6950 or 6xxx)
Core i7-960, 3x2gb DDR3, ASUS Rampage III Gene
Sharp Aquos LC52D85U 
/root, /boot, /usr is on Corsair Force GT 120gb, /home, /tmp, on 1TB WD Black